# Broadcast Receiver listening to text selection

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

Is it possible to define a broadcast receiver that listens for text selection made on any application

Comment: I've never heard of anything like that.

Comment: Yes Why not just ask developer to broadcast intent at that time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no broadcast intent generated on text selection, so what you try to do is impossible.

If there are specific apps that you'd like to provide them with external functionality, than you can contact the developers and ask them to explicitly broadcast an intent that you can receive and respond to.

Hope that helps..