# Android text selection receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, textselection

Is it possible to make `Service` which will get notified when text selection anywhere in Android system (google chrome, other apps) appears?

I thought to make `BroadcastReceiver` with `PROCESS_TEXT` action but it does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12145139/2757664

Comment: It's from '12. Things could change...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the new Android M feature of "Text Selection" to be offered from outside of your app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518089/how-to-use-the-new-android-m-feature-of-text-selection-to-be-offered-from-outs)